# Bootstrap Image Slider Carousel not working

Tags: html, css, django-templates, bootstrap-5

So I am trying to build a website using Django to show images using an image slider carousel, but the code doesn't seem to work. I have no idea why. Instead of being a carousel the images are stacked on top of one another.

[image]

My html:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <div class="img-property-slide-wrap">
        <div class="img-property-slide">
        <img src="{{ object.image1.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
        <img src="{{ object.image2.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
        <img src="{{ object.image3.url }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My style.css:

```
.img-property-slide-wrap {
  position: relative; }
  .img-property-slide-wrap .tns-outer .tns-inner {
    padding-bottom: 100px !important; }
  .img-property-slide-wrap .tns-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 40px;
    z-index: 2; }
    .img-property-slide-wrap .tns-nav button {
      background: none;
      border: none;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 2px;
      position: relative; }
      .img-property-slide-wrap .tns-nav button:active, .img-property-slide-wrap .tns-nav button:focus {
        outline: none; }
      .img-property-slide-wrap .tns-nav button:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        width: 7px;
        height: 7px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        right: 0;
        -webkit-transition: .3s all ease;
        -o-transition: .3s all ease;
        transition: .3s all ease; }
      .img-property-slide-wrap .tns-nav button.tns-nav-active:before {
        background-color: #1f6f8b; }
```

Comment: Please provide some information about what you have tried and how it failed. Have you loaded the JavaScript for the carousel ? If so - is the script for the carousel configured and triggered after the HTML page has loaded ?

Comment: I have no javascript for the carousel

Comment: But this css, for some reason is not loaded. Hence it is not working, cuz I think the code should work.

Comment: It says in the headline that it is a Bootstrap carousel and according to the documentation it needs both CSS and JavaScript.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#basic-examples

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Is the CSS loaded from an external file ?

Comment: The style.css file is being loaded, but only `.img-property-slide-wrap {
    position: relative;
}` this line is shown in the console for the `img-property-slide-wrap` class

Comment: Allright .. so the CSS is being loaded. Is that all of the CSS working or only that one line you mention ?  What about the JavaScript ? Is that being loaded and run after it has been loaded ?

Comment: As I told you I have no JS file for carousel image slider. I got no code from any website for JS.

Comment: Please take a look at the fine documentation that I have linked to in a previous post. There you will find the JS and how to implement it.

Comment: Can you please write the JS and CSS for my carousel html as an answer? That would be better cause I am hopeless atp.

Comment: In the documentation you can find examples of how to use the carousel. The examples even have two buttons in the upper right corner so you can chose to "Copy to clipboard" and also see it running clicking "Edit on StackBlitz"

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML markup has some structural issues for carousel. Check carousel example in bootstrap docs.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Here is a corrected version of the code and it shows the image in carousel form. Also don't forget to include the necessary dependencies for bootstrap in the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <title>Bootstrap Image Carousel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div id="imageCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/147411/italy-mountains-dawn-daybreak-147411.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1200"
                    class="d-block w-100"
                    alt="Image 1"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/36717/amazing-animal-beautiful-beautifull.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1200"
                    class="d-block w-100"
                    alt="Image 2"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <img
                    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/247599/pexels-photo-247599.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1200"
                    class="d-block w-100"
                    alt="Image 3"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <a
                class="carousel-control-prev"
                href="#imageCarousel"
                role="button"
                data-slide="prev"
              >
                <span
                  class="carousel-control-prev-icon"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
              </a>
              <a
                class="carousel-control-next"
                href="#imageCarousel"
                role="button"
                data-slide="next"
              >
                <span
                  class="carousel-control-next-icon"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                ></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.0.8/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```